# Which countable ordinals are "Barwise compact" for $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega_1}$?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, computability-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Barwise compactness says (as a special case) that whenever $\alpha$ is countable and admissible, $T\subseteq\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}\cap L_\alpha$ is $\alpha$-c.e., and every subset of $T$ which is an element of $L_\alpha$ is satisfiable, then $T$ itself is satisfiable.

Now say that a countable ordinal $\alpha$ is **$\omega_1$-Barwise** iff it satisfies the analogue of the above property with $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}$ replaced by $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega_1}$. This is a nontrivial notion:

- **$\omega_1^{CK}$ is not $\omega_1$-Barwise.** Take the usual computable infinitary theory used in the construction of a Harrison order via Barwise compactness and add a sentence asserting well-orderability. In fact this gives a fairly large lower bound on the smallest $\omega_1$-Barwise ordinal, although I have no idea whether this bound is at all good (and I suspect it's actually quite bad).
- **There exist $\omega_1$-Barwise ordinals.** Let $(T_i)_{i<\omega_1}$ be an enumeration of the $\omega_1$-c.e. $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega_1}$-theories such that for each admissible $\alpha<\omega_1$ the sequence $(T_i\cap L_\alpha)_{i<\alpha}$ enumerates the $\alpha$-c.e. $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega_1}$-theories. For each $i<\omega_1$ let $\rho(i)=i$ if $T_i$ is countably satisfiable and $\min\{i+\alpha: T_i\cap L_\alpha\models\perp\}$ if $T_i$ is not countably satisfiable. There is then some $\theta<\omega_1$ such that $\rho(i)<\theta$ for all $i<\theta$; this $\theta$ is $\omega_1$-Barwise. *(Note that this is extremely coarse: the same argument works for basically any logic at all, and we can moreover replace "$\Sigma_1$" with "definable" by restricting attention to elementary initial segments of $L_{\omega_1}$ so that "unsatisfiability is preserved" as we progress up $\omega_1$.)*

I'd love an exact characterization of $\omega_1$-Barwiseness, but I suspect that's rather difficult. Instead, the following seems more approachable:

> What is the smallest $\omega_1$-Barwise ordinal?

*(Of course in some sense we have the answer already: it's the smallest $\omega_1$-Barwise ordinal. I'm looking for a characterization in terms of more standard notions - e.g. restricted elementary substructures and Mostowski collapses, levels of $L$ satisfying some first-order theory or having natural "superstructures" satisfying some first-order theory, supremum of ordinals computable in some higher-type functional, etc.)*